# Alarm manager not work while application is closed

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to send notification at specific time every day. Now, I can send notification. However, the problem is when an application is closed. It seems that alarm manager does not works and does not send notification.

Here is an activity:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        noti();
    }

    public void noti(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReminderAlarmManagerBroadcast.class);
        intent.setAction("com.myapplication.game");
        intent.putExtra("TITLE" ,"Title");
        intent.putExtra("HOUR" ,14);
        intent.putExtra("MINUTE" ,22);
        int request = new Random().nextInt((1000000 - 1) + 1) + 1;
        Calendar alarmStartTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE,22);
        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),request, intent,  0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);//set repeating every week
        }
    }
}
```

**BroadCastReciever**

```java
public class ReminderAlarmManagerBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String LOCK_NAME_STATIC = "tag:com.myapplication.game";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, LOCK_NAME_STATIC);
        wakeLock.acquire();
        Time now = new Time();
        now.setToNow();
        if (intent.getAction().contains("com.myapplication.game")) {
            String title = intent.getExtras().getString("TITLE");
            int hour = intent.getExtras().getInt("HOUR");
            int minute = intent.getExtras().getInt("MINUTE");
            if (hour == now.hour && minute == now.minute) {
                createNotificationChannel(context, title);
            }
        }
        wakeLock.release();
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel(Context context, String title) {
        Intent intent = null;
        intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        int request = new Random().nextInt((1000000 - 1) + 1) + 1;
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, request, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        String channelId = "1";
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText("message")
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            notificationManager.notify(request, notificationBuilder.build());
        } else {
            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager1 = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
            notificationManager1.notify(request, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
    }
}
```

and I add BroadCastReciever to manifest like this:

```xml
<receiver
    android:name=".ReminderAlarmManagerBroadcast"
    android:directBootAware="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.dadehgostar.tazkereh" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and I also have these permission:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

**How to fix it to send notification while the application is closed?**

Answer (score 0):

Define your intent as follows and you are good to go:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("YOUR_CUSTOM_ACTION");
intent.setClass(this, ReminderAlarmManagerBroadcast.class);
```

You are expected to search more. As of android 8.0 and above, no implicit `broadcast` declaration is permitted. To solve this, you need to set the target `receiver` class in your `intent`. This makes it explicit, meaning no other `broadcasts` will be received by the `receiver` class, other than this one.

Comment: I cant understand you need to set the target receiver class in your intent . can you describe it more .

Comment: Prior to android 8, when you declared a receiver with a given action, it could receive all the broadcasts with the same action. It caused both security problems and performance issues. Since android Oreo afterwards, a broadcast receiver can just receive those broadcasts which explicitly declare the class (here `ReminderAlarmManagerBroadcast.class`)  as their target.